# Angular : Data from child undefined

Tags: javascript, html, angular, data-binding

simple problem : I want to pass data from a child to its parent when clicking on a button, but the data is always undefined in the parent.
I've looked at : [Angular's Documentation](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-listens-for-child-event) and at the multitude of posts already sorting this problem out but i'm still stuck with it so..

The child component (`<left-panel>`) have a button with a `(click)="handleAddTea()"` event handler. When clicked the button `emit()` the event through an `EventEmitter` that has the `@Output` decorator as required.

And I bind this `EventEmitter`to a handler in the parent templete with a $ sign in front of the data as documented : `(addTeaEvent)="handleAddTeaEvent($data)"`
But when the `handleAddTeaEvent` function trigger the data is `undefined`

Here is the related code in the child component :

```js
  @Output()
  addTeaEvent: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

  handleAddTea() {
    console.log('Add Tea Clicked sending to parent..');
    this.addTeaEvent.emit(this.mainTitle)
  }
```

```html
<button class="btn flex__item--middle btn--large btn--call-to-action" (click)="handleAddTea()">
    {{addBtnText}}
  </button>
```

And here is the related code in the  parent component :

```js
handleAddTeaEvent(stuff: any) {
    console.log('from parent', stuff);
    
  }
```

```html
<left-panel mainTitle="Add a tea" addBtnText="Add tea" (addTeaEvent)="handleAddTeaEvent($data)"></left-panel>
```

Why is it undefined ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `$event` instead of `$data` in event listener:

```
<left-panel mainTitle="Add a tea" addBtnText="Add tea" (addTeaEvent)="handleAddTeaEvent($event)"></left-panel>
```

For further reading: https://angular.io/guide/user-input